# Twitter bootstrap: nav tabs and pills not contained within hero example 'container' element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have recently downloaded TB 2, and have started to familiarize myself with it. I am creating a page based on the hero example.

I am creating a page based off the hero example. The page content area is the element with class 'container' in my markup. The layout I am creating is as follows (within the 'container' element), create two columns:

- Left hand column (66.66% of page area)
- Right hand column (33.33% of page area)

The left hand column will contain two rows, with the top row containing nav pills, and the bottom row containing nav tabs.

This is the HTML in the 'container' element:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="page-left-column" class="span8">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">  
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Pill 1</a></li>     
                <li><a href="#">Pill 2</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Pill 3</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#">Pill 4</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#">Pill 5</a></li>   
            </ul> 
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">  
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="page-right-column" class="span4">
        <div class="row">
        </div>

        <div class="row">
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Using Firebug, I find that both the tab and pills have spilt out of their containing element, so in the case of the nav tabs, where content is on a page, the text is no longer lining up on the left handside of the column - i.e. the text is displayed OUTSIDE the column.

Is there something wrong with the markup above?

Comment: please show a bit more here. I set up a quick example http://jsfiddle.net/imwill/mkSmR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solutions:**

- Each tags such as `input`, `div`, `table`, `ul`  should have a `span*` class. Not required, but recommended.
- In order to implement `%` rather than `px` on values: `row-fluid`, `container-fluid` should be applied. Child span* will just follow its containers.
- The recommended pattern is: container, span, container, span, container, span, etc.
- Container may be a (container or row (fluid or not fluid)). Span may be any elements/tags inside a container.

**CSS:**

```
        .border {
            border: 1px solid #afafaf;
        }
        #page-right-column {
            margin:0;
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="container border">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div id="page-left-column" class="span8">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">  
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Pill 1</a></li>     
                                <li><a href="#">Pill 2</a></li>  
                                <li><a href="#">Pill 3</a></li>   
                                <li><a href="#">Pill 4</a></li>   
                                <li><a href="#">Pill 5</a></li>   
                            </ul> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span12">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">  
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>  
                                <li><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>   
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End of #page-left-column -->
                <div id="page-right-column" class="span4">
                    <div class="row-fluid border">
                        <div class="span12">
                            First row of right column. 
                        </div>
                        <div class="span12">
                            Second row of right column
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- End of #page-right-column -->
            </div><!-- End of .container-fluid -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- End of .container -->
```

Comment: +1 for the code. It works beautifully now (even though I don't fully understand why). Could you please explain somemore what I was doing wrong and how your markup fixes the issue?. Thanks

Comment: When using percentage values on width, you should use `.row-fluid` instead of `.row`. On your first container `.row`, should have been `.row-fluid`. This will calculate the child width with a percentage value. Meaning, instead of `width:200px;` , it was changed to `width:20%;`. Another thing is, the pattern of your child tags are `.row` > `.span8` > `.row` > `ul`. Where `ul`, either should be inside a `div.span*` or has an additional attribute of `.span*`. The span width will always depend on the parent container. In this case, `.row`.

Comment: In short, you need to decide whether the contents' width will be percentage or pixels. Either it's going to be `.row` or `.row-fluid`.